# Execute PHP Shell command with $_GET['request']

Tags: php, get

I've create a script that execute some part from the php script by calling the 'request' GET,

Is there a way to execute the script via SHELL like this : `php -q script.php?request`

I've executed but nothing is happening.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Also worth reading: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: `$_GET` is empty when the script is called from CLI. You should use `$argv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would typically place the arguments after the command:

```
php -q script.php request arg2
```

inside the file it would be read with

```
$request = $argv[1];
$arg2 = $argv[2];
```

`($argv[0];)` is the script name

**Edit**

from the command line:

```
php -q script.php request
```

and inside script.php:

```
 $request = $argv[1];
if(isset($request){
 echo 'run this part';
}
```

**Edit2**

I suppose if the arguments are conditional you could do something like:

```
php -q script.php 'arg1:foo-arg2:bar'
```

and

```
$request = $argv[1];
$parts=explode('-',$request);
$args=array();
foreach($parts as $part){   
   $arg=explode(':',$part);
   $args[$arg[0]]=$arg[1];
}
```

that would give you :

```
array(
    arg1 => 'foo', 
    arg2 => 'bar'
      )
```

Comment: I really cannot catch this, is a bit unclear for me, lets say that i have this: if(isset($_GET['request'])){echo 'run this part';}

Comment: i understand, the issue is that if i type a second $_GET['request2'] it execute request

Comment: yup ok that would be `php -q script.php request request2` and `$request2 = $argv[2];` etc

Comment: i got undefinied offset instead the execution of script, but even if i type scrip.php argument1 argument2 argument3 the part of script that execute is argument1 and work only with 1 offest on add the second it return undefinied offset

Comment: in any case, i solve the issue switching the PHP -q with GET

Comment: ok see the above edit